# Проверка на наличие записи MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется `php` файл который выводит название городов. Нужно сделать так, что бы перед выводом информации шла проверка на наличие записи в БД. Т.Е. файл стучится в БД, проверяет, существует ли такая запись:

`$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Key WHERE Name LIKE '%".$Name."%'");`

Если запись есть, то вытянуть из БД "соответствующую информацию".

Если записи нет, то запустить один скрипт, с генерировать "соответствующую информацию" добавить в БД. И при следующей загрузке страницы после проверки на существование, она там была.

Comment: В чем собственно проблема? С чем помочь надо?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan Собственно с самой проверкой. Как ее сделать

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Key WHERE Name LIKE :NameTemplate` и проверить, что там - ноль или не очень...

Comment: @Akina попробовал `Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given в функции include() `

Comment: почему **mysql_num_rows** ??

Comment: mysql_*. **Внимание** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Key WHERE Name LIKE '%".$Name."%'");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
//do Something 
}
```

Comment: Только лучше `SELECT 1` вместо `*`. Незачем гонять трафик со всеми полями таблицы.

Comment: да,так лучше,но запрос не мой,я всего лишь указал как сделать проверку.

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки существования данных по запросу предназначена функция EXISTS

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Key WHERE Name LIKE ?)
```

Она специальным образом оптимизирована для таких случаев. Выполнение подзапроса останавливается, когда найдена первая совпадающая строка.

Примерно таким же(зависит от деталей реализации) эффектом обладает запрос

```
SELECT 1 FROM Key WHERE Name LIKE ? LIMIT 1
```

---

Однако, утверждение

> Если запись есть, то вытянуть из БД "соответствующую информацию".

говорит о том, что данные, если они есть вы всё равно планируете получать полностью.

Поэтому, всё, что вам нужно - проверить [mysqli_result::$num_rows](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)